# Transfering ASP Classic Pages from Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, linux, asp-classic, move

Has anyone tried a solution to host ASP classic pages on something else than IIS/Windows? I'm wondering if it would be a good idea to try one of the solutions for that problem. I know about Sun Java System Active Server Pages (or Chilisoft) but haven't tried it. Is there any big problems with those solutions? Does the hosted code need change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with [Apache::ASP](http://apache-asp.org./) in your Linux, but I'll use it just for the meantime until can migrate the application to other language with better support (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, Ruby... even .Net with Mono).

Note that Apache:ASP can't manage classes, so you'll need to recode your classes to just variables and functions. Well, classes in classic ASP aren't so much complicated than just variables and functions...

Comment: Not handling classes is the least of `Apache::ASP` problems: it does not handle `VBScript`, the language used in virtually all existing Classic ASP websites. You would have to port *all* code to `PerlScript`, which kind of defeats the point in using Apache::ASP at all

Answer (score 3):

There is a program that exists called [ASP 2 PHP](http://asp2php.naken.cc/). With that you could migrate your application to PHP. The project leader does not recommend using it continuously as it is not, nor ever will be 100% perfect.

There is also an [FAQ](http://asp2php.naken.cc/faq.php) and a [Notes](http://asp2php.naken.cc/notes.php) page to get a glimpse of the problems that you may encounter while using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get in troubles trying that ... :(

If it was ASP.NET I'd encourage you to use Mono, but for classic ASP I don't think there are that many solutions, but I *could* be wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

I had client who chose, unknowingly, an ISP with form of ASP emulation under Linux many years ago. The program I installed didn't work properly because filenames in Windows are not case-sensitive, in Unix they are. It was a whole pile if fail. Include files, URLs, form posts, image filenames, you name it.